# Disable eclipse plugins programmatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to create my own update system and during update I need to remove some plugins but they are  in use - how to disable it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Get a [`BundleContext`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) via the [bundle activator](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html) of the plugin that should stop the other plugin/bundle and do something like:

```java
for (Bundle bundle: bundleContext.getBundles()) {
    if ("my.bundle.symbolic.name".equals(bundle.getSymbolicName())) {
        bundle.stop();
        break;
    }
}
```

See also [`Bundle.stop(int options)`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#stop(int))

Comment: Thank you. It works, but what about of fragments? It still be busy -  I can not delete it also. Even after stop a host plugin.

Comment: I guess you have not only stop but also [uninstall](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#uninstall())
 the bundle.